# I am trying to load a pretrained tensorflow model checkpoint while queing the task in Redis. But it only shows "restoring checkpoint"

Tags: python, tensorflow, redis

I am trying to load a pretrained tensorflow model checkpoint while queuing the task in Redis. But it only shows "restoring checkpoint" and no response after that. Although the checkpoint is loaded successfully when called without queuing in redis.What could be possible reasons for this issue.Is there a way to check what is actually happening in redis?

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection

import pandas as pd
numDimensions = 300
maxSeqLength = 250
batchSize = 24
lstmUnits = 64
numClasses = 2
iterations = 100000

import numpy as np
wordsList = np.load('wordsList.npy').tolist()
wordsList = [word.decode('UTF-8') for word in wordsList] #Encode words as UTF-8
wordVectors = np.load('wordVectors.npy')

#tf.Graph().as_default()


# Removes punctuation, parentheses, question marks, etc., and leaves only alphanumeric characters
import re
strip_special_chars = re.compile("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+")

def cleanSentences(string):
    string = string.lower().replace("<br />", " ")
    return re.sub(strip_special_chars, "", string.lower())

def getSentenceMatrix(sentence):
    arr = np.zeros([batchSize, maxSeqLength])
    sentenceMatrix = np.zeros([batchSize,maxSeqLength], dtype='int32')
    cleanedSentence = cleanSentences(sentence)
    split = cleanedSentence.split()
    for indexCounter,word in enumerate(split):
        try:
            sentenceMatrix[0,indexCounter] = wordsList.index(word)
        except ValueError:
            sentenceMatrix[0,indexCounter] = 399999 #Vector for unkown words
    return sentenceMatrix



def small(post):
    import tensorflow as tf
    tf.reset_default_graph()

    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batchSize, numClasses])
    input_data = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [batchSize, maxSeqLength])

    data = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([batchSize, maxSeqLength, numDimensions]),dtype=tf.float32)
    data = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(wordVectors,input_data)

    lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstmUnits)
    lstmCell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell=lstmCell, output_keep_prob=0.25)
    value, _ = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(lstmCell, data, dtype=tf.float32)

    weight = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([lstmUnits, numClasses]))
    bias = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[numClasses]))
    value = tf.transpose(value, [1, 0, 2])
    last = tf.gather(value, int(value.get_shape()[0]) - 1)
    prediction = (tf.matmul(last, weight) + bias)

    correctPred = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(labels,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correctPred, tf.float32))

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('pos_negative'))
    print('sentiment called')
    inputText=post
    a = 'Positive'
    b = 'Negative'
    inputMatrix = getSentenceMatrix(inputText)
    print('matrix formed')

    predictedSentiment = sess.run(prediction, {input_data: inputMatrix})[0]

    #if (predictedSentiment[0] > predictedSentiment[1]):
    #  return a
    #else:
    #    return b
    print('done')
    return 'Positive'


#response = small('the car was good')

listen = ['default']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(list(map(Queue, listen)))
        worker.work()
```